# Firestore not giving the data even though it exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const Ref = db.collection("characters").doc("mario");
const doc = Ref.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
} else {
  console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}
```

I have double-checked that this doc does exist in my firestore database but my console log is giving me: "No such document!"

i have also checked the permissions for read and write and they are open.

Comment: Since we can't see your database, there's nothing we can do to validate if this error message is correct.  But I suspect it is correct anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` method is asynchronous so it returns a promise, and you'll have to `await` its results:

```
const doc = await Ref.get();
```

In your current code, you're essentially checking whether the promise has a `exists` property that has a value, which isn't the case.